# Transferring bitcoins out of an old multibit wallet

Tags: multibit, unconfirmed-transactions, wallet-recovery

A few years ago I bought bitcoins and I've kept it in a Multibit 0.5.15 (Mac OSX) wallet. Now I want to either sell thes bitcoins or send it to a different wallet. I already made a transfer but since I can't manually specify a higher fee in this old Multibit app my transfer stays on pending/unconfirmed.

My question is, how do I transfer this money? Is there any way to export either my wallet or transfer my money to another wallet?

Also I have no idea what to do with this pending transaction. I see no way to cancel it in Multibit 0.5.15.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pywallet I believe can sort all your problems out. Will let u import the wallet addresses and should let u send the btc again to invalidate the original transaction.

You can either export the private keys from the old Mac wallet and import them into a new wallet. Note once u have exported the private keys u should consider the address compromised and not leave any btc in it

Comment: Thank you. I ended up solving this without the use of pywallet because multibit 0.5.15 lets you export the private keys. With these private keys I managed to import the wallet and transfer the BTC.